# why gmail is not connected to xmpp in android

Tags: android

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        String host = getText(R.id.host);
        String port = getText(R.id.port);
        String service = getText(R.id.service);
        String username = getText(R.id.userid);
        String password = getText(R.id.password);

        // Create a connection
        ConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
                new ConnectionConfiguration(host, Integer.parseInt(port), service);
        XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

        try {
            connection.connect();
            Log.i("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Connected to " + connection.getHost());
        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
            Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
            xmppClient.setConnection(null);
        }
        try {
            connection.login(username, password);
            Log.i("XMPPClient", "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

            // Set the status to available
            Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
            connection.sendPacket(presence);
            xmppClient.setConnection(connection);
        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to log in as " + username);
            Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
                xmppClient.setConnection(null);
        }
```

Error is coming at connection.login(username,password);
This is working fine at laptop, But when i running the same app into desktop, an unknownHostexception,timeoutexception is coming 
please help me

Answer (score 0):

This error comes if you are already log in via same user name and password or if you don't have Internet permission in Manifest File